# Mobile hotspot device vs phone personal hotspot

Tags: mobile

We are going to an island in Maine which has "Fair" 4G LT coverage per our carrier (TMobile).  We would like to maximize our networking ability so we can work remotely.  What is the best way to do this?

We can use our phone's Personal Hotspot and upgrade our plan (from standard to Magenta Plus) which would provide 20GB Personal Hotspot 4G LTE data.  This still assumes that TMobile coverage is decent.

Another option is to buy a [mobile hotspot](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07YDN7P1C).  Presumably a mobile hotspot will use the best available network and wouldn't tie us to one carrier.

Is the best option to go with the mobile hotspot?  Or is there a better option?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here, as are questions that solicit primarily opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your smartphone is already receiving service from a cellular provider, whereas this "mobile hotspot" you are thinking of is just basically a hotspot that (according to its description on the product page), will get a free amount of data initially, after which you will need to pay money recharge the data.  Thus, to use it you will be paying more money than rather just using your smartphone's hotspot.  It does state that it utilizes no sim to connect, which is possible in the case of a device that has an eSIM (embedded SIM) or eUICC (embedded Universal Integrated Circuit Card).  This eSIM or eUICC probably utilizes the "GlocalMe" network, which may run like "Ting" which operates on multiple networks.  This however arises another major issue, which is what cellular providers in the US does "GlocalMe" run on.  Another notable issue is the number of cellular bands used in the US, that the device supports.  Majority of US cellular providers utilize AWS/E-AWS, which only a select number of countries in the world utilize.  Thus, not all phones sold by not well-known brands support this band.  Of course, there are other bands that are utilized in the US, and the device may utilize those bands.

On the other hand, with the "mobile hotspot" you do not need to keep your cellphone in range of other devices that it otherwise would have been tethered to.  Therefore, you can be able to use your cellphone a little out of range of the other devices.  This also will not be causing an overhead on your smartphone's cellular data speed, that would have been present if your smartphone’s hotspot was used and tethered devices as well as yourself were using your smartphones cellular data service to connect to the internet.

Your smartphone's hotspot is a better option in the scenario that you are describing.  In the scenario where the "mobile hotspot" supports all bands used by US cellular providers or runs on good cellular providers in the US, then this device is better.  You will have to do a bit of research into what cellular providers does this device work on, and how well does it work on those cellular providers compared to your cellphone.

Answer (score 0):

I gather you aren't familiar with the US wireless market.

Hotspots function just like phones -- specific to a carrier, 'tho there's often some overlap in bands. A generic "world" device will almost certainly have issues with any random US carrier, because it's not built specifically for that carrier's bands.

At any rate, it'll need a SIM; and that SIM will be for a specific carrier network. But the carrier must still allow the device on their network. (Case in point, a Google Nexus 7 tablet will physically work on Sprint's network -- with a Sprint SIM -- but Sprint doesn't allow them on the network.)

There are multi-network SIMs, but I'm not aware of any retail outlet selling them. (eg. Google Fi)

--

All that said, hotspots are usually better suited as a "router" than a phone... better wifi support, lower power, can host more peers, etc. But a phone will definitely work. (esp. when it's something we all carry around all the time anyway.)